# Fix img-src CSP with Nuxt 3 Security

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

How to fix this error with Nuxt 3  and `nuxt-security`?

```
Refused to load the image 'https://www.mywebsite.com/logo.svg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
```